# How to see most recent data submitted at top of page with PHP/mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, html-table

I am displaying a table from data in a mySQL database (which is stored by users filling out a form). How can I display it so that the most recent data submitted is at the top of the page?

Here is my code to retrieve the data from the table and display it. Currently, I can arrange the table by name, email, etc.

```
<?php
// connect to the database
require 'connect.php';

if(isset($_GET['orderby']))
{
    $orderby = $_GET['orderby'];
    $query = "SELECT name_first,name_last,email,company,city,state,phone,session,optout FROM table
            ORDER by ".mysql_real_escape_string($orderby)."";
}
else
{
    $query = "SELECT name_first,name_last,email,company,city,state,phone,session,optout FROM table";
}

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
?>

<table style='width: 60%; text-align: left;' cellpadding = '1'>
<tr bgcolor=#000090>
<th><a href=prospstud.php?orderby=name_first><FONT COLOR = #FFFFFF><b>First</b></th>
<th><a href=prospstud.php?orderby=name_last><FONT COLOR = #FFFFFF><b>Last</b></th>
<th><a href=prospstud.php?orderby=email><FONT COLOR = #FFFFFF><b>Email</b></th>
<th><a href=prospstud.php?orderby=phone><FONT COLOR = #FFFFFF><b>Phone</b></th>
<th><a href=prospstud.php?orderby=session><FONT COLOR = #FFFFFF><b>Session</b></th>
<th><a href=prospstud.php?orderby=company><FONT COLOR = #FFFFFF><b>Company</b></th>
<th><a href=prospstud.php?orderby=city><FONT COLOR = #FFFFFF><b>City</b></th>
<th><a href=prospstud.php?orderby=state><FONT COLOR = #FFFFFF><b>State</b></th>
<th><a href=prospstud.php?orderby=optout><FONT COLOR = #FFFFFF><b>Opted Out?</b></th>
</tr>

<?php

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $name_first = $row['name_first'];
    $name_last = $row['name_last'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $phone = $row['phone'];
    $session = $row['session'];
    $company = $row['company'];
    $city = $row['city'];
    $state = $row['phone'];
    $optout = $row['optout'];

    echo "<tr bgcolor=#ABB5F6>
    <td>$name_first</td>
    <td>$name_last</td>
    <td>$email</td>
    <td>$phone</td>
    <td>$session</td>
    <td>$company</td>
    <td>$city</td>
    <td>$state</td>
    <td>$optout</td>
    </tr>";
}
```

Comment: Do you mean PHP sessions, most recent data submitted, etc?

Comment: Sorry. I meant most recent data submitted. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can save a timestamp value in the database each time a session is accessed/created.

You can then use:

```
ORDER BY timestampRow DESC
```

in your SQL query.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately most of the data was already stored. Is there a way to do it for previous data?

Comment: @myom edit your question and include information about your table.

Comment: Sorry, that's not possible. You can only get time information if you store it in a row at the time of entry into a database.

Comment: By default, the table shows the oldest data submitted at the top, and the most recent data submitted at the bottom. Is there a way to reverse this?

Comment: you could use array reverse (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) and reverse the order of the array returned from mysql_fetch_assoc.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an auto-incremented ID on your database table.
And when you do the select, you select the data wth the max id. Like so:

```
    SELECT "id,name_first,name_last,email,company,city,state,phone,session,optout FROM table" WHERE id >=MAX(id);
```